# javascript not firing in modal popup-PHP

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I have modal popup which opens on button click. I have a select dropdown which has user type, according to that user type , it fetches respective data from mysql table and populates in another select drop down. I am using `.on(change)` function , here is my modal popup's select dropdown:

```
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">User Type</label>
          <select name="user_type" id="user_type" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 100%;" required="">
                            <option selected="selected" value="">Select user type </option>
                            <option  value="admin">Admin </option>
                            <option  value="manager">Manager </option>
                            <option  value="executive">Executive </option>
                        
                            </select>



            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Employee/User</label>
          <select name="user" id="user" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 100%;" required="" disabled>
                            <option selected="selected" value="">Select Employee </option>
                            </select>
```

My Javascipt originally I had:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#user_type').on(function() {
   var usertype = $(this).val();
   $('#user').prop( "disabled", false );

   
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'T_userData.php',
            data:'usertype='+usertype,
            success:function(html){
                //alert(html);
                $('#sub_prod').html(html);
                //$('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
            }
        }); 
    
});
});
</script>
```

then I changed it to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#trgtmodal').on("change","#user_type",function() {
    var usertype = $(this).val();
   $('#user').prop( "disabled", false );

   
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'T_userData.php',
            data:'usertype='+usertype,
            success:function(html){
                //alert(html);
                $('#sub_prod').html(html);
                //$('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
            }
        }); 
    
});
});
</script>
```

still not working. If needed I can post the whole Modal Popup HTML markup. Please advise

Comment: change this `$('#trgtmodal')`  to `$(document)` and see if that works

Comment: hi, if you mean `$(document).ready(function(){
$('#user_type').on(function() {` then I have already tried

Comment: no i mean to say `$(document).on("change","#user_type",function() {//your code..});` i have already tested this its working fine .